# Method not called in correct order / asyncronous method

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables, jquery-events

I have a problem here when I try to load these functions in this order:
By the way, I'm using Datatables and jQuery which I am sure many of you probably know already.

```
currPage = LookupPts.oTable.fnPagingInfo();
LookupPts.oTable.fnReloadAjax();
LookupPts.oTable.fnPageChange(currPage.iPage);
```

It fails when I try to run `fnPageChange()` immediately after `fnReloadAjax()`
I know this is a timing issue due to the asyncronous `fnReloadAjax`,
My question is how can I have the `fnPageChange` get called when `fnReloadAjax` is complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement a callback as Javascript is a non-blocking language and does not work the commands step by step. You therefore need a callback that runs after the method finished.

I just looked at the definition of the ReloadAjax method (I never used this). And if I got the right one which is this: function ( oSettings, sNewSource, fnCallback, bStandingRedraw )) the following code should work:

```
currPage = LookupPts.oTable.fnPagingInfo();
LookupPts.oTable.fnReloadAjax(null, null, function(){
   LookupPts.oTable.fnPageChange(currPage.iPage);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, well I got it fixed.

Before I posted my problem, I tried the same method as described from all of you but I still got the same problem. For some reason it would not work.

What did I have to do to fix it?

What I found after debugging the pluggin was that the order of arguments were not correct. The parameters for the pluggin are: oSettings, sNewSource, bStandingRedraw, fnCallback.

I noticed when the method was called my arguments were not in the right order. My order was oSettings = object, nNewSource = null, fnCallback = null, bStandingRedraw = function.

The trick was to put the arguments in the correct order like so, with the callback as second in the parameter list:

```
                        currPage = LookupPts.oTable.fnPagingInfo();
                        LookupPts.oTable.fnReloadAjax(null, function(){
                           LookupPts.oTable.fnPageChange(currPage.iPage);
                           console.log("finished loading the page details");
                        }, null);
```

I got confused with the first parameter oSettings. By the way how does the first parameter get loaded with the object?
Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [plugin documentation](http://datatables.net/plug-ins/api) the `fnReloadAjax()` has this signature:

> fnReloadAjax = function ( oSettings, sNewSource, fnCallback, bStandingRedraw )
>   { }

Therefore you can pass a callback function as the third parameter to be executed on completion of the AJAX call. Try this:

```
currPage = LookupPts.oTable.fnPagingInfo();
LookupPts.oTable.fnReloadAjax(null, null, function() { 
    LookupPts.oTable.fnPageChange(currPage.iPage);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
currPage = LookupPts.oTable.fnPagingInfo();
LookupPts.oTable.fnReloadAjax(null, null, function() {
    LookupPts.oTable.fnPageChange(currPage.iPage);
}
```